# in socket programming, can accept() the same listening socket in multi-process(thread)?

Tags: sockets, pthreads

i.e.

1. open a listening socket in parent process
2. call epoll_wait(listening_socket) in child1,child2,child3....
3. call accept in each child if there is connection request

Answer (score 5):

In general, it's not a good idea to have multiple threads performing IO on the same socket without some kind of synchronization between them. In your scenario, it's possible you'd see something like:

- incoming connection request wakes up epoll_wait in all N child threads
- all N threads call `accept`, 1 call succeeds, N-1 block (or fail, if your listening socket is non-blocking)

The more usual approach is to have the parent thread loop calling `accept` on the listening socket, and starting a child thread for each incoming request. (Or, if you're concerned about thread creation overhead, you can have a pool of child threads that wait on a condition variable when idle; the parent adds the newly-accepted socket to a queue and uses `pthread_cond_signal` to wake a child to handle it.)

Comment: More acurately, you should not have multiple threads performing the SAME KIND OF IO on a socket at the same time.  You can have one thread reading from the socket while another thread is writing to the same socket, and that is perfectly safe.  But you cannot have two or more threads reading at the same time, or writing at the same time, or listening at the same time, without synchronizing them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can but your example is a little incomplete:

1. Create **listening_socket**
2. Create **epoll set** using *epoll_create*
3. Register **listening_socket** to the **epoll set** using *epoll_ctl*
4. call *epoll_wait*(**epoll set**) in child1,child2,child3....
5. call *accept* in each child if there is connection request

epoll_wait makes sures that only one thread gets the connection event and only that thread will call accept.

If you create two epoll sets and register your listening_socket to both of them you will receive the event twice, once per epoll set, and this is not recommended.

You may refer to this tutorial http://www.devshed.com/c/a/BrainDump/Linux-Files-and-the-Event-Poll-Interface/ and search some interesting discussions about epoll in this forum http://www.developerweb.net/forum/ to learn more.

For more elaborate examples you can always refer to the libev, libevent or nginx source code.